# How to resize an NTFS volume to fill the partition?

Tags: windows

Having only the Windows ISO file I installed Windows XP to a virtual machine, and moved it [successfully](https://superuser.com/questions/483773/how-to-copy-virtualbox-vdi-contents-to-a-partition-and-dual-boot-the-os-from-it/484505#484505) to a physical partition on my machine.

Because I did a direct partition copy, from the virtual parition to the physical, Windows thinks it has still 10GB size, but the partition it sits in is 59GB.

Is there any way or hack to make it recognize the entire partition? Without data loss of course, respecting my ext4 or other linux partitions Windows XP does not know about.

Diskpart simply reject the `extend` command on it.

EDIT: I also heard people experiencing the same, when resizing the partition with GParted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot resize the a partition that's mounted. That's why diskpart refuses the `extend`.

You need to boot an Ubuntu live CD or pendrive.

And run `ntfsresize`

Here is a little tutorial: http://linuxtechres.blogspot.hu/2007/08/how-to-use-ntfsresize-from-command-line.html

Basically it says:

You need to do the following commands:

- `fdisk -l` to find out which partition to touch.
- `ntfsresize --info /dev/<parition>` to get partition info.
- `ntfsresize --no-action --size <new volume size> <partition>` to do a dry run. (you can use units in the size eg. 12000M)
- `ntfsresize --size <new volume size> <partition>` to do the resize. This will schedule a chkdsk check so boot the Windows to finish it.

You need to be in `disk` group to carry out the action or run it as root.

Comment: “You cannot resize the a partition that's mounted.” This may have been true back in 2012, but it isn’t today. Extending a volume is possible online. // I also very much advice against using anything but Windows to manipulate NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 9):

Use the **diskpart** command [`extend filesystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/extend) instead. It extends the filesystem, even if it is mounted.

(command found on a [Microsoft forum](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/832316/the-partition-size-is-extended-but-the-file-system-remains-the-origina))

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I've been looking for

Comment: Same here exactly what I was looking for. +1!