# how do I resolve this inconsistency between windows 10 pro being described as (just)windows 10 in the boot menu and as windows 10 pro within itself?

Tags: windows-10

how do I resolve this inconsistency between windows 10 pro being described as (just)windows 10 in the boot menu and as windows 10 pro within itself?

Notice the one it lists as 'current' it lists as windows 10 not windows 10 pro. But windows itself lists itself as pro.

[image]

I only actually have one partition and one version of windows installed..

but I had created another partition (maybe with windows installation media, maybe with gparted), put an image of another partition on it as an experiment,  then deleted the partition with gparted. Perhaps I should've deleted the partition with windows installation media.  It's possible the windows 10 installation media asked me to click windows 10, or windows 10 pro, and I might've clicked 'windows 10', prior to creating the second partition, though I deleted that partition anyway albeit with gparted.

At the moment I get two versions of windows come up in the boot menu, and there should only be one. And not only that..  I could potentially delete one of them from the boot menu, as there are things online about how to do that..

But what I  don't understand and can't find information on, is why it describes it as windows 10 when it is windows 10 pro.

Some comments here https://pastebin.com/raw/iP635t5Z

Comment: You would have to use edit your Boot Configuration Data (BCD) entry to fix this inconsistency.  What have you tried?  You should determine which entry is pointing to your installation, remove the duplicate entry, and rename the working entry to whatever value you want.

Comment: @barlop - So you should answer the question, if that is the solution to your question, what is display is user configurable.  It could say "Magical Unicorns Are Cool" and it would not make a difference.  I wasn't going to vote to close this question, although a question that has received an answer in the comment section, should be answered properly.

Comment: It was automatic to a point, for whatever reason you had an existing entry in the BCD, a new entry was added and to avoid confusion the name was different.  What determines the name I don’t know, but it’s (sort of) clear only one entry works.  I would love to answer this question, but without more information about your BCD, that isn’t possible

Comment: @barlop - I like to submit answers that are tailored to the user's question.  By submitting information on which partition each BCD entry on your system points to, I can provide an answer, that properly answers your question. In any event, I am reporting every single comment, since this commentary, is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The different *versions* are simply different [friendly names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/changing-the-friendly-name-of-a-boot-entry) in the boot entry. Any text *could* appear there (up to 70 characters) but certain entries (and formats thereof) are created automatically.

So no disk space is wasted it's useful to check that indeed you do have only one partition, a shortcut (non-certain, but useful) way is to [edit the boot.ini file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/changing-the-friendly-name-of-a-boot-entry#editing-the-bootini-file):

```
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows 10" /fastdetect
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows 10 Professional" /fastdetect
```

Notice that the beginning of each line is identical, that means that both boot entries boot to the same partition (it's not absolute *proof* that you only have one partition, but fixing that involves something else). Simply delete the first line. Note that doing so gives you only one boot option, and with the high speed of booting nowadays you'll have a bit of difficulty getting back to the menu without a *pause*.

It's useful to have two entries, one safe mode. See: "[How to Add Safe Mode to the Windows 8 and 10 Boot Menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/245175/how-to-add-safe-mode-to-the-windows-8-and-10-boot-menu/)" and "[TechNet - Adding Boot Entries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ff541231(v=vs.96))" for more info.

Your additional boot entry could have easily been created to point to the deleted partition, that's why it's a good idea to manually check your boot.ini and see what's up. See the end of the webpage at the TechNet link, just type bcdedit at the command prompt (as admin) to see how it's configured.

In the newest versions of Windows the boot.ini has been replaced with the `C:\boot\bcd` file, see: [How to Rebuild the BCD in Windows](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508).