# Is there any way to turn off tamper protection using command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, regedit, windows-defender

I work with many test PCs, so I want to automate the procedure for installing OS and setting up.

- Disabling anti-virus is one of the set-up steps via the below, with it working well for a while, but now doesn't work, showing error `Access Denied`:

  ```powershell
  Reg Add "HKLM\software\policies\microsoft\windows defender" /v DisableAntiSpyware /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
  ```

I found that "[Tamper Protection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4490103/windows-10-prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection)" [blocks](https://superuser.com/questions/1500683/cant-disable-windows-defender-using-group-policy-and-registry/1500687) attempts to modify registry keys for Windows Defender; I know how to turn it off using GUI, but for automating, I'd like to do this via CLI.

- I tried to modify the registry key for "Tamper Protection" via `regedit`, but it seems it blocks the attempt to modify itself

Is there any way to turn off "Tamper Protection" using command line?

Comment: The permissions on those registry keys need to be changed before they can be modified, you need to take ownership of the key and all sub keys.

Comment: Given you are doing all this for fresh windows installations, have a look at NT Lite, to slipstream your windows. You can basically bake in all the changes into a fresh OS install. All you do is install using your custom USB stick and no further changes are necessary anymore. Once in a while, you have to update your USB stick, but that is easily done.

Comment: Another option to @LPChip's great suggestion is [MDT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/mdt/) (**M**icrosoft **D**eployment **T**oolkit), with more details in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1480619/529800) answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need permission to change some registry keys.
[NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/) was also mentioned - a great program.

I use [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/) tool to do it programatically.
Changing permissions for a registry key with SetACL:

```
SetACL.exe -on "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\YourService" -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr "n:Administrators"
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR you can't.

Even if you take permission of the key and revoke permissions to all other accounts/groups, the key is still protected and unable to be changed. [MS's official answer is to either use Intune for your organization or do it manually.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-itpro-docs/issues/6009#issuecomment-591263914)

Comment: Please quote the relevant information from your link.

Comment: How to turn it off if Windows Security app is not starting?