# Repurpose old computer into offsite backup server

Tags: backup, nas, storage

So I have this old machine: Intel Pentium E5200, 2GB of DDR2 RAM, Radeon R5 230 2GB GPU, Gigabyte G31M-S2L MOBO which is currently sitting doing nothing. I thought of turning it into a NAS server or a router, but in a couple of weeks i'm moving for college and can't take the old machine with me. Also this thing is going to spend electricity and I can't take advantage of it running 24/7, so a NAS solution doesn't make sense for me.

My main workstation machine (which I'll be taking with me) has 400GB of raw data right now that are not backed up anywhere. It's mainly videos, imagery, large projects and similar stuff I'll be working with. Both the current and the next place i'll be moving into have slow 24MBps connections so I won't be using VPN or anything with a toll on transfer speed.

The solution I think fits best, is set up the old machine with some linux distro (cause old hardware) then remotely turn it off when I need to upload my files from the other city, leave it overnight transfering my stuff (cause slow internet) then once I'm done turn it off remotely. And have a safe and secure offsite backup of my files.

I'm guessing it's possible but how do I do it exactly? Also I'm looking for the cheapest solution available (ideally just a bunch of hdds for the old machine). Thank you.

Comment: You realise 24mbps is the **download** speed, upload will be more like 2mbps, that's going to be 2 or 3 months to transfer 400GB nights-only, by which time how much more data will you have accrued?

Comment: I do realise that, and upload is on the 1mbps side of things, but slow backup is better than no backup. I was thinking i could transfer the 400GB locally, then upload any new projects remotely, couple of hundreds of MBs at the time...

Comment: Which part are you asking about, specifically?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, how do i set up such configuration from scratch. What OS on the old machine, how to configure it for remote file transfer (as well as turning on off).

Comment: @Tetsujin The 400GB transfer is supposed to happen while I'm still here. I have no idea how to carry out the rest of my glorious genius plan.

Comment: Why not take the old machine with you, remove the GPU (it's not needed for CLI access), and transfer backups to it manually via USB (it likely doesn't have a Gbit ethernet, so USB2 will be ~4x faster, or via AC wireless card, which would be ~1.5 faster than USB2)?  If you're backing up a Windows OS, create a [WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1474837/529800) with `/compress:max` set.  Remotely backing up to an offsite server with 1mbit/s uplink (125KB/s) is impractical and pointless for transfering several hundred GB.

Comment: This is your project and I won't make an authoritative Answer.  One suggestion : See if the BIOS allows automatic power-on .  Then you can schedule auto-power-on at 1 AM in the morning, run a backup script over Ethernet from wherever, then include a "shutdown" after the backup has completed.  Then you don't have to worry about using electricity all the time.

Comment: @JW0914 Unfortunately I can't take it with me as there's no space in the apparentment nor the car... I won't be backing up windows or any software really, just raw files. Impractical yes, pointless? I would disagree with that. I guess my hands are tied.

Comment: @DuckHunterZx It's impractical and pointless to attempt to backup 400GB uncompressed over a 125KB/s uplink.  Physics is physics: if you were able to maintain the max speed of 125KB/s every second of every day, it would take 37.925 days (`400 * 1024` = `409600000 / 125 / 60 / 60 / 24`).  There are better solutions than this, such as an external HDD which is stored offsite after a backup is performed, but what you're wanting to do with a 1mbit/s uplink is simply not realistic.

Comment: @JW0914 Let me repeat, 400GB is the amount of data I currently have on my PC. If I can set up my machine as a backup server fast enough (before I move), I could transfer the files locally, through my home network, a USB cable or something similar. The remote part is for future projects, small bits at a time.

Comment: Considering your link limitations, how would you restore those backups?

Comment: @gronostaj If I'm on a rush and it's an active project, through the same slow link. If its a finished project, then I'll wait to make a trip and transfer them locally.